# Get "You can only create a user with a password in a contained database." error when login as sa

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2017

Just got a simple query:

```
CREATE USER [xxxxx] WITH PASSWORD='xxxxxx'
```

But when I login as sa, I get this error:

```
You can only create a user with a password in a contained database
```

But when I login as windows credentials, it runs fine.

Do I need to set anything on the sa account?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/creating-user-for-a-single-contained-database

Comment: @zarruq I did the first query before, that didn't work. But second query made it work. A bit confused now about the relationship. Why different login method makes a difference to the create user query.